# Ditto Command For Facebook App Preview

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, shell, fbsdk

I am new in IOS development and FBSDK Framework. I am trying to get list of facebook friends and it needs to set user_friends permission so I read the documentation and I found out that first I have to enable from App Preview on facebook developer console, on there I need to insert my application as zip file to review by facebook team it told me to write this command.

```
ditto -ck --sequesterRsrc --keepParent 'ls -1 -d -t ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My_App_NAME/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Quran Collabe.app' | head -n 1 '/Users/demo/Desktop/Quran.zip'
```

I tried but I got this error

```
head: Error reading /Users/demo/Desktop/Quran.zip
ditto: No destination
Usage: ditto [ <options> ] src [ ... src ] dst
```

I search a lot but not found the solution to solve it.
Please help me figure out how to solve it

Comment: You are aware that user_friends will only give you friends that granted user_friends permission to the app. Not all friends

Comment: @wizkid, yes I know it. do you know about my problem and that error?